# Крестик поверх текста

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн

Крестик, закрывающий это уведомление, показывается поверх заголовка этого же уведомления:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Завершено? А почему не "Не воспроизводится"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Извиняюсь, не та метка! Конечно, надо было [meta-tag:статус-завершено-и-будет-доступно-в-следующей-сборке]

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky серьезно? В ближайшей сборке можно будет посмотреть страницу, где упомянутый крестик не перекрывает упомянутый текст? Насколько я понимаю, фактически «завершение» свелось к тому, что кнопка «Новые» перестала быть доступной, а стало быть и всплывающее окно, которое к ней привязано. И если это действительно так, то «статус-завершено» тут притянут за уши.